# past tense and present tense in a single sequence

Tags: tense

"Ever since Eric turned 18 years old he parties every weekend." ?
 It is an example from a BBC English course. I have my doubts about using the past tense and the present tense in a single sentence.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the sentence. It probably should be "Ever since Eric **has** turned 18-years-old, he parties every weekend."

Comment: So even though there seems to be nothing wrong with the sentence, it would sound better with the present perfect after "Eric" (has turned), but I think the speaker has just elided the words "the day" after "since": "Ever since **the day** Eric turned 18-years-old, he parties every weekend."

Comment: This comes up all the time. Be assured that there is no stricture against using multiple tenses in a single sentence, if they're used correctly. See [this answer on EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/5663/2303).

Comment: I'm curious why you think mixing tenses is ungrammatical in English?  Did you read this in a textbook, or is it something you were taught?

Answer (score 2):

Ever since Eric turned 18 years old, he parties every weekend.

You can use the present simple in the main clause, but it's more appropriate or ideal to use the present perfect instead of the present simple as follows:

Ever since Eric turned 18 years old, he has partied every weekend.
.